# Two way ANOVA when one independant variable is not Categorical

Tags: statistical-significance, anova, mixed-type-data, two-way

I am doing a test on doctors' training level and the number on duty. One IV is training level, the other IV is the number of doctors on duty. The DV is the number of patients seen.

There are two levels to training level (trained vs. untrained) and three levels to Number on Duty (one, two, and three).

I want to do a two-way ANOVA but I understand both independent variables need to be Categorical. I think my Number Deployed variable isn't categorical.

Can someone help me if this matters? Is there a different test I should use? Or is there a correction I can apply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [linear-model](/questions/tagged/linear-model), of which the ANOVA is a special case involving only categorical predictors. Linear models can use continuous predictors too and when at least one predictor is continuous, it's typically called a [regression](/questions/tagged/regression) (though the term is most commonly used when all predictors are continuous).

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful.